# Move scroll of a div with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im trying to move the scroll of a div with jquery, but i dont know what im doing wrong.

Here is the code that im using:

```
$("#CategoryList").animate({ scrollLeft: "=-5" }, "slow");
```

where CategoryList is the ID of my div with scroll.

Could you give me a hand?
Thanks in advance.
Josema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `"+=5"` and animate the `#FixedWindow`, not your CategoryList

```
function InitList(){
  $("#NavigateBackward").hover(function(){
      $("#FixedWindow").animate({ scrollLeft: "+=5" }, "slow");
  });

  $("#NavigateFordward").hover(function(){
    $("#FixedWindow").animate({ scrollLeft: "-=5" }, "slow");
  });
}
```

.

```
<span id="NavigateBackward"><</span>
<span id="NavigateFordward">></span>
<div id="FixedWindow" style="width:129px;overflow:hidden;">
     <div id="CategoryList" style="width:2000px;overflow:auto;">
         <p class="MiniCategory" style="display:inline;">Category 1</p>
         <p class="MiniCategory" style="display:inline;">Category 2</p>
         <p class="MiniCategory" style="display:inline;">Category 3</p>
         <p class="MiniCategory" style="display:inline;">Category 4</p>
         <p class="MiniCategory" style="display:inline;">Category 5</p>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead (notice it's `-=` not `=-`):

```
$("#CategoryList").animate({ scrollLeft: "-=5" }, "slow");
```